# $u_{n+2}=6u_{n+1}-u_n,\, u_0=2,u_1=6$ Prove that $u_n >0,\forall n\in \mathbb N$ (By strong induction)

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

Let  sequence $(u_n)$ definded by $$u_{n+2}=6u_{n+1}-u_n,\, u_0=2,u_1=6$$ Prove  that $u_n >0,\forall n\in \mathbb N$  by [strong induction](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematical_Proof/Methods_of_Proof/Proof_by_Induction)

I am unable to demonstrate the result using a strong induction . but I have proof with this induction .

Let $P(n)$ the properties $\forall n\in \mathbb N,u_{n+1}>u_n>0$

$P(0)$ is true

Suppose that $u_{n+1}>u_n>0$,

We have  $u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}=4u_{n+1}+ (u_{n+1}-u_n)$ and then $u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}>0.$

But how to prove the result by strong induction ?

**edit

by strong induction, i mean to prove the exactly property  $$P(n):\quad \forall n\in \mathbb N, \, u_n >0$$
For that, we assume that $P(k)$ is true $\forall k\leq n$, and we must prove that $P(n+1)$ is true**

Comment: Induction is a special case of strong induction, so if you have shown something using induction you've also shown it using strong induction.

Comment: Easy , as per @AlonsoDelfín 's comment, you have already done it with strong induction, you can present the proof as if it is strong induction,

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without induction.

Let $b_{n+2} = 6b_{n+1} - 5b_{n}$. For every $n$, $u_n > b_n$. Then the characteristics solution of $b_n$ is given by $c_1 \alpha^n + c_2 \beta^n$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of $x^2-6x+5 = (x-1)(x-5) = 0$.

Therefore, $b_n = c_1 5^n + c_2$. The initial conditions give $2 = c_1 (1) + c_2$, $6 = c_1(5) + c_2$, from which we get that $c_1 = c_2 = 1$. Thus $b_n = 5^n + 1$. Since we have that $b_1, b_2 ≥ 0$, and that $b_{n+1} - b_n = 5^{n+1} - 5^{n} = 5^n (5 - 1) $$= 4 \cdot 5^n > 0$ for $n \in \mathbb N$, $b_n > 0$ and thus $u_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: thank's but the question is how to use strong induction.

Comment: Well you have already proved it using strong induction. The point of my answer is to show an alternative method.